# Python　Kivyでの文字の切り替えが動作しない

Tags: python, kivy

### **前提・実現したいこと**

Python Kivyを学ぶために時計を作成したいのですが、文字の切り替えが出来ません。
ちゃんと動作させるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか

### **該当のソースコード**

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty 
import datetime
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
from time import strftime
#ウインドウの幅と高さの設定
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 700)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 400)
#1でサイズ変更可、0はサイズ変更不可
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 1)
#kvファイルの読み込み
Builder.load_file("update_label.kv")

class MyLayout(Widget):
    time = StringProperty('')
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        d = datetime.datetime.today()
        self.ids.text_t.text = strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    def update(self):
        d = self.ids.text_t.text = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.ids.text_t.text = self.ids.text_t.text = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print(d)

class DispimageApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "window"
        crudeclock = MyLayout()
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt:crudeclock.update(), 1)
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DispimageApp().run()
```

```
<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20
        Label:
            id : text_t
            text: root.time
            font_size: 100
            markup: True
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            size_hint_y: 0.5
```

### **補足情報**

エラーの出力はありませんでした。

Comment: 「文字の切り替え」とはどのようなことを指すのでしょう？ フォントの変更？ 表示時刻の更新？ その他？ それはソースコードのどの部分で行おうとしていますか？ もう少し詳細を記述してください。あと参考にした書籍や記事等があればそれも記載してください。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/foxwz4jqfx95dl) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: １秒間隔で表示文字を現在の時間に更新し続けるプログラムを作成しようと考えています。

Comment: Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt:crudeclock.update(), 1)にて更新の発火をしています。

Comment: Widgetの外でintervalを指定したりlambdaを使ったりしているので上手くいっていないのでは？ これらの記事を参考にしてみてはどうでしょう？ [KivyでのImageの更新](https://qiita.com/taashi/items/e68c527bba13854eb555), [Python - Kivy - キャンバス(回転し続ける長方形、Clock、schedule_intervalメソッド、コールバック関数)](https://www.mkamimura.com/2019/02/Python-Kivy-Clock-scheduleinterval.html), [Kivyで簡単なアプリを作ってみる](https://tkitao.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/10/10/083252), [【Kivy】処理と処理の間で任意の時間待つ方法](https://niwakomablog.com/kivy-schedule-once/)